# Is display:run-in usable? If not, what’s the alternative?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a web page to mimic the appearance of a legal document in which section titles are bold-faced and run into the body of the first paragraph of the section. Something like this:

> **Area.** Minimum lot size five (5) acres with a minimum of two (2) acres excluding wetlands. (Amended March 1992.)
>
> **Frontage.** Two hundred (200) feet on a Class V or better road. (Amended March 1999.)
>
> **Setbacks.** Two hundred (200) feet from all park lines.

The obvious HTML would be

```
<h3>Area.</h3>
<p>Minimum lot size five (5) acres with a minimum of two (2) acres excluding wetlands. 
(Amended March 1992.)</p>
<h3>Frontage.</h3>
<p>Two hundred (200) feet on a Class V or better road. (Amended March 1999.)</p>
<h3>Setbacks.</h3>
<p>Two hundred (200) feet from all park lines.</p>
```

This looks like exactly what CSS `display: run-in` was created for. But from what I’ve read, `display: run-in` is pretty-much dead.

Is there a good alternative?

Comment: Opinion question can be frowned upon in here by some mods.

Comment: It is exactly what `display:run-in` is for. And the desirability of being able to do it is why it's not dead yet - it still appears in the latest candidate recommendation of the `display` spec, and the latest editors draft. But the box munging rules are distinctly clunky - there's a lot of what-happens-if cases that need to be resolved and so have stopped implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case for float:

```css
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<h3>Area.</h3>
<p>Minimum lot size five (5) acres with a minimum of two (2) acres excluding wetlands. (Amended March 1992.)</p>
<h3>Frontage.</h3>
<p>Two hundred (200) feet on a Class V or better road. (Amended March 1999.)</p>
<h3>Setbacks.</h3>
<p>Two hundred (200) feet from all park lines.</p>
```